# Undefined Index in mysql populated Select when setting selected

Tags: php, mysql, select, undefined

I have a select dropdown that is being populated and displayed correctly from a mysql query:

```
  <select name="title">
  <option></option>
  <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($title_data)) {
      echo '<option value=' . $row["title"];
      echo '>' . $row["title"];
      echo '</option>';
    } 
  ?>
  </select>
```

When I add code to check which row was selected, I get an undefined index error for each row in the query results:

```
  <select name="title">
  <option></option>
  <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($title_data)) {
      echo '<option value=' . $row["title"];
      if($_POST["title"] == $row["title"]) {
        echo ' selected';
      }
      echo '>' . $row["title"];
      echo '</option>';
    } 
  ?>
  </select>
```

I'm realtively new to this and may be missing something obvious.  I had checked the posts and did not see this particular example where I am using a while loop from a query and trying to echo the selected attribute.  The actual error text is inserted into the dropdown box:

> Notice: Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\indexdb.php on line 215 >Analyst I" and appears for each row in the dropdown box.

I apologize if this has been covered as I stated, this is my first php code and is a protype only.  This is the only hurdle I have not been able to overcome.

Comment: Please include your code in the question. You should also consider switching from `mysql_*` to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) as `mysql` is [officially](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) deprecated. You are not sanitizing your user input which could allow people to use [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attacks to deface your site. Look in too [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: @sawmkw It is best to include the code in the post or pastebin rather than an image. But code in post = A MUST pastebin = easier formatting so we can look at.

Comment: Check if `POST` is populated first. `!empty(`. I'd provide an example but I can't copy/paste part of an image.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper pastebin is not suggested either. The question is the best place for the code.

Comment: @Script47 I was saying it could be possible to include it in pastebin. I've seen many post that includes the code but it looks like a pile of garbage and it's very hard to look at. Pastebin you can just copy and paste and it'll auto format.

Comment: The error should indicate what is undefined?

Comment: I realized that each of my drop down values has a space, such as "Clinical Nurse".  I'm not picking up the entire value in the $_POST which in this example contains only "Clinical".  I apologize for missing this.  Thanks @chris85 for pointing me in that right direction.

Comment: @sawmkw what's the status here, does the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate the `value` attribute's data.

```
echo '<option value="' . $row["title"] . '" ';
```

Then to resolve the undefined index first check that the field is populated:

```
if(!empty($_POST["title"]) && $_POST["title"] == $row["title"]) {
```